# Why doesn't Javascript:history.back() show form values?

Tags: html, forms, header, cross-browser, meta-tags

I am just working on a HTML formular which submits some values to php. Now if I encounter some problems there, I am currently showing the error and a link with `javascript:history.back()` in it.

In chrome, the form opens again with all the values filled in like in the last try. But the same does not work in Firefox, the form is displayed completely empty. Same in Internet Explorer.

Is there any way to set the behaviour of chrome as standard, for example any PHP header or html meta tags?

Thanks for help!

Comment: javascript:history.back() will be the same as clicking your browser's back-button. This means that it's up to the browser to implement caching of your form data. This link is quite helpful WRT your question https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $_SESSION to save the answer, when the browser is closed the results will not be saved. But using history.back(); will as you will have it to check whether $_SESSION['name'] is set. If it is I would parse it through maybe AJAX in order to get some flow in your web application.

Comment: I think I'll use something self-made here using Ajax, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If history.back() is the same as clicking the back button in the browser, then I think that saving (or not saving) form values has more to do with that browsers settings than the history.back() function itself.

I just did a quick test in firefox and chrome, and the same happens when using the back button (chrome remembers everything except passwords, firefox does not).